# Regarding populating data in csv table of hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a history table with fields `mid`, `id`, `month`, `year`. I want to create a `table1` with same schema.

**History table data**

```
Mid id month year   
1   1  1     2017
2   1  3     2017
3   1  6     2017
```

I want to generate a main table as below

**table1**

```
Mid id month year       
1   1  1     2017
2   1  2     2017    
2   1  3     2017    
3   1  4     2017    
3   1  5     2017    
3   1  6     2017
```

Here we need to populate the values in `table1` for the missing months.

Here in business, for table `history`, the `month=3` means the data is same for 2nd month, as it is not mentioned in history.

Similarly, in history table, `month=6` is given. Which means, the same records of 6th month should be duplicated for 5th, 4th month as they are not present in the table.

Is it possible in Apache Hive.

Comment: some sapledata  and result

Comment: @sandeeprawat the sample data and expected result is given above

Comment: Crate at dimension in hive and do outer join and get result ..https://thisdataguy.com/2018/04/24/create-a-time-dimension-table-in-pure-hive-sql/